# Lógica para exibir dados - Fatiar dias

Tags: php, mysql, lógica

Boa noite.

Utilizando PHP, busco dados com MySQL. A tabela tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
ID |      dataHoraInicio     |      dataHoraTermino    |
1  |   2017-05-08 11:28:40   |   2017-05-08 17:52:12   |
2  |   2017-05-08 18:34:02   |   2017-05-10 09:02:57   |
3  |   2017-05-10 09:44:31   |   2017-05-10 13:22:10   |
```

Supondo que só tenha esses 3 registros na tabela, em uma consulta simples, sem WHERE, retornariam logicamente as 3 linhas.

Note que o primeiro registro inicia no dia 08, às 11:28:40, e finaliza no mesmo dia, às 17:52:12.

O segundo registro inicia no mesmo dia que o registro 1, mas só finaliza dois dias depois, às 09:02:57 do dia 10.

O terceiro registro inicia e finaliza no mesmo dia, como o primeiro registro.

Minha questão seria em "fatiar" o segundo registro, para que a saída da consulta fique como:

```
ID |      dataHoraInicio     |      dataHoraTermino    |
1  |   2017-05-08 11:28:40   |   2017-05-08 17:52:12   |
2  |   2017-05-08 18:34:02   |   2017-05-08 23:59:59   | <-- hora final alterada
2b |   2017-05-09 00:00:00   |   2017-05-09 23:59:59   | <-- dia "fatiado"
2c |   2017-05-10 00:00:00   |   2017-05-10 09:02:57   | <-- hora inicial alterada
3  |   2017-05-10 09:44:31   |   2017-05-10 13:22:10   |
```

A ideia é que em cada linha retornada, não ocorra "transbordamento" do tempo para o dia seguinte, mas sim que "fatie", indicando cada dia específico.

O ID não importa no resultado final. Tentei de 3 formas, mas ou acrescenta dias além do esperado, ou não completa os horários como deveria.

Toda dica será bem vinda, seja resolvendo via PHP, ou diretamente na consulta SQL. Abraços.

Comment: Por que precisa "fatiar"? Não pode trabalhar com as datas e horas como vem? Pois, talvez para resolver seu problema não seja necessário fazer o "fatiamento"

Comment: Opa David, boa noite. Preciso pois esse fatiamento será utilizado em outra parte do script. Os resultados precisam sim, sair como explicado na questão. Abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solução

```
// Intervalos vindos do banco de dados:
$dates = [
    ["2017-05-08 11:28:40", "2017-05-08 17:52:12"],
    ["2017-05-08 18:34:02", "2017-05-10 09:02:57"],
    ["2017-05-10 09:44:31", "2017-05-10 13:22:10"]
];

// Percorre os intervalos de datas:
foreach ($dates as $index => $date)
{

    // (1) Cria um objeto DateTime para cada:
    $start = new DateTime($date[0]);
    $end   = new DateTime($date[1]);

    // (2) Se a diferença entre as datas for superior a um dia:
    if ($end->diff($start)->format("%a") > 0)
    {
        // (3) Lista de fatias do intervalo:
        $interval = [];

        // (4) Enquanto a diferença for maior que um dia:
        while ($end->diff($start)->format("%a") > 0)
        {
            // (4.1) Define a fatia do intervalo para o dia:
            $sliceStart = clone $start;
            $sliceEnd   = clone $start;

            $interval[] = [$sliceStart->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $sliceEnd->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")];

            // (4.2) Incrementa em um dia a data de início:
            $start->modify("+1 day")->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        }

        // (5) Define o intervalo para o último dia:
        $interval[] = [$start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $end->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")];

        // (6) Substitui o intervalo original pela lista de fatias:
        $dates[$index] = $interval;
    }
}

print_r($dates);
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/k4Qx27).

#### Explicação

A variável `$dates` armazena uma lista de intervalos com as datas vindas do banco de dados. O primeiro valor refere-se à data de início e o segundo à data final. Com um laço de repetição itera-se sobre esses intervalos, fazendo:

1. Cria um objeto do tipo `DateTime` para cada data, tanto inicial quanto final;
2. Se a diferença entre as datas for inferior ou igual a zero, não é feito nada com o intervalo, mas se for superior a zero, prossiga o algoritmo;
3. Cria um *array* para armazenar todos as fatias do intervalo;
4. Enquanto a diferença entre as datas em dias for maior que zero, faça:

   4.1. Adiciona à lista de fatias a fatia referente à data inicial até o horário 23:59:59 do mesmo dia;

   4.2. Modifica a data inicial incrementando um dia e voltando o horário para 00:00:00;
5. Quando a diferença em dias for zero, define a última fatia do intervalo, entre a data inicial, que será o horário 00:00:00 do último dia, até a data final;
6. Substitui na lista de intervalos original adicionando a lista de fatias;

#### Resultado

A lista de intervalos inicial:

```
$dates = [
    ["2017-05-08 11:28:40", "2017-05-08 17:52:12"],
    ["2017-05-08 18:34:02", "2017-05-10 09:02:57"],
    ["2017-05-10 09:44:31", "2017-05-10 13:22:10"]
];
```

Após executar o código, resulta em:

```
$dates = [
  ['2017-05-08 11:28:40', '2017-05-08 17:52:12'],
  [
    ['2017-05-08 18:34:02', '2017-05-08 23:59:59'],
    ['2017-05-09 00:00:00', '2017-05-09 23:59:59'],
    ['2017-05-10 00:00:00', '2017-05-10 09:02:57']
  ],
  ['2017-05-10 09:44:31', '2017-05-10 13:22:10']
];
```

Ou seja, quando o intervalo definido no banco de dados representa um intervalo de mais de um dia, ele é substituído por uma lista de fatias que compõe o intervalo.

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss, obrigado por sua resposta. Note que se acrescentar um item ao array, com os seguintes valores ["2017-05-10 22:17:54", "2017-05-11 03:41:25"], ele não irá "fatiar", como pode ser visto aqui https://ideone.com/vlKFLz